# How to programmatically(python) authenticate username/password using OS users

Tags: python, linux, authentication

I'm writing a python program which allow user to login to it. I don't want to implement my own authentication but would rather take advantage of the OS(linux) mechanism. That is, when the user is trying to sign in my app by inputing username/password pair(which should be a valid OS user), I need to authenticate the pair by the OS. How to do that ? It may need the subprocess module, yet I've tried with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) via [Python PAM](http://atlee.ca/software/pam/) or similar

Answer (score 2):

That should be possible by having your script read the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files, which contain details about usernames and passwords on a Linux system. Do note that the script will have to have read access to the files, which depending on the situation may or may not be possible.

Here are two good articles explaining the format of those files, which should tell you everything you need to know in order to have your script read and understand them:

- [Understanding /etc/passwd File Format](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)
- [Understanding /etc/shadow File Format](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/)

By the way, when it talks about *encrypted password*, it means that it has been encrypted using the DES algorithm. You'll probably need to use [pyDes](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html) or another python implementation of the DES algorithm in order for your script to create an encrypted password that it can compare to the one in `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: `DES` isn't a hash, and `/etc/shadow` passwords (that have been through `crypt`) may be hashed differently. Additionally, reading `/etc/shadow` typically requires root privileges

Comment: Whoops, fixed my answer about `DES` not being a hash. The possibility that another algorithm was used, and how that is noted in `/etc/shadow` is discussed in the second link. As I said at the start of my answer, depending on the situation this solution may not be a reasonable one.

Comment: Under Linux, Python's [crypt](http://docs.python.org/library/crypt.html) module can be used to verify the hashes in `/etc/shadow` no matter what the format, since `crypt.crypt` will call the underlying OS routine that PAM uses. As well, the [spwd](http://docs.python.org/library/spwd.html) module can be used to read `/etc/shadow`.